# SWITCH statement not working while an identical IF statement is (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, switch-statement

I wrote a short program that converts numbers to roman numerals. It contains two very similar switch statements, one of which is working perfectly well, and the other one (commented out in the snippet), is not. The console logs the "error" message , suggesting the parameter "e" of the function doesn't reach the switch somehow.
However, when I used an "if" instead of switch, it works. What's going on there!?

Thanks in advance.

```js
// d - digit being converted
// e - digit's place in the number (sorry, don't know the right term in English)

function convertToRoman(num) {
 
 var convert = function(d, e){
  
  var a = '';
  var b = '';
  var c = '';
  
  /* 
  switch (e){
   case '1': a='I'; b='V'; c='X'; break;
   case '2': a='X'; b='L'; c='C'; break;
   case '3': a='C'; b='D'; c='M'; break;
   case '4': a='M';                break;
   default:  console.log('error')}
  */
  
  if (e===1) {a='I'; b='V'; c='X';}
  else if (e===2) {a='X'; b='L'; c='C';}
  else if (e===3) {a='C'; b='D'; c='M';}
  else if (e===4) {a='M';}
  else  {console.log('error')}
   
  var s='';
  switch (d){
   case '0': s = '';    break;
   case '1': s = a;    break;
   case '2': s = a+a;  break;
   case '3': s = a+a+a;      break;
   case '4': s = a+b;  break;
   case '5': s = b;    break;
   case '6': s = b+a;  break;
   case '7': s = b+a+a;      break;
   case '8': s = b+a+a+a;      break;
   case '9': s = a+c;  break;
   default:  s = '#';  break; }
  return s;
 };

 arr = String(num).split("");

 for (i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  var e = arr.length-i;
  arr[i] = convert(arr[i], e);
 }
  
  return arr.join('');
}
convertToRoman(501);
```

Comment: try setting your cases to use numbers instead of chars, if someone could confirm: i think that switch statements use strict comparisons for switch (`===` vs `==`), and seeing how numbers worked for you in the if statements, I think that might solve your issue

Comment: The answer is fairly obvious. You're comparing strings in your switch statement and integers in your if/else.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do call `convert` you are passing in a `char` for d and a `num` for e, so the commented switch statement will need to use numbers, not characters, which is essentially what you are doing with the if, else if, else replacement.